# Problem inputting Indian rupee sign via XKB layout using Win key as level 3 shift

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm from India but mostly just using the default "US" keyboard layout. I tried to modify it to input the *Indian Rupee Sign* `U+20B9`. I modified `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` as follows:

```
    key <AE04> {    [         4,    dollar,      U20B9, U00A7 ]    }; // 20B9 = indian rupee sign, 00A7 = section sign
```

Of course, I cleaned out the old `*.xkm` in `/var/lib/xkb/`, rebooted etc but still I am not able to input `U+20B9` using my level 3 key (<kbd>Win</kbd> key) though I am getting `U+00A7` section mark using level 4 (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>).

I tried to remap the character to another key (`R`) but that didn't work either. I tried to use the inbuilt:

```
    include "rupeesign(4)"
```

... but that didn't work either. I am using Kubuntu Trusty 64 bit.